# HttpClient timeout using HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

.NET Core 3.1 Console application on Windows, I'm trying to figure out why the `httpClient.Timeout` does not seem to be working when getting the content after using [HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // if using HttpCompletionOption this timeout doesn't work
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    var uri = new Uri("http://brokenlinkcheckerchecker.com/files/200MB.zip");

    // will not timeout
    //using var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    // will timeout after 5s with a TaskCanceledException
    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    Console.WriteLine($"Status code is {httpResponseMessage.StatusCode}. Press any key to get content");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("getting content");

    var html = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"finished and length is {html.Length}");
}
```

Have also tried a `CancellationToken`

```cs
// will not timeout
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
using var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,
 cts.Token);
```

and `ReadAsStreamAsync`

```cs
// will not timeout
using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    string fileToWriteTo = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
    }
}
```

I learned about `HttpCompletionOption` from this great article:
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread-to-improve-httpclient-performance-dotnet

**Update**
Using @StephenCleary answer below of passing the cancellationToken into the `CopyToAsync` method this now works as expected.

I've included the updated code below which shows copying into a `MemoryStream` then into a string, which I found tricky to find how to do. For my use case this is good.

```cs
string html;
await using (var streamToReadFrom = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
await using (var streamToWriteTo = new MemoryStream())
{
    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo, cts.Token);
    // careful of what encoding - read from incoming MIME
    html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(streamToWriteTo.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting timeout here?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - Good question! 

I'm interested as to why the timeout behaviour appears to change when using the HttpCompletionOption. 

I'm also writing code where I'd like an Http exception to be thrown after x seconds even if the client is still successfully downloading content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect `HttpClient.Timeout` to only apply to the `GetAsync` part of the request. `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` means "consider the `Get` complete when the response headers are read", so it's complete. So the problem is that it just doesn't apply to reading from the stream.

I recommend using [Polly's Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) instead of `HttpClient.Timeout`; Polly is a generic library that can be used to timeout *any* operation.

If you don't want to use Polly at this time, you can pass the `CancellationToken` to `Stream.CopyToAsync`.

Comment: Much appreciated. I've updated the question with a working answer now. Next step https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly as had forgotten about this excellent library!