# Timeout when using HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, timeout, httpclient

Wondering if anyone could help me in understanding timeouts when HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead is used.  Given the code below:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    const string url = "https://url";
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        ... do some processing on stream ...
    }
}
```

Is my understanding correct that:

- the timeout of the client.GetAsync call is 5s (because of `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`)?  and because `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` is used, `client.GetAsync` is successfully completed once the headers are downloaded
- the stream processing is not affected by the `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)` configuration
- stream processing does not have a timeout / time limit (on the client side at least).  so even for a very large file (say 1GB), it would theoretically be ok for the stream processing to take many minutes

Thanks.

Sorry, one other related question, say the stream processing consisted of a CopyTo call:

```
await stream.CopyToAsync(destStream);
```

Does the default `CopyToAsync` call above (no cancellation token) have any sort of time restriction?

Comment: I would suggest try implementing [logger for .netcore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line)  or [logger for .net](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial) and log the lines between each `awaits`.

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996606/1752270). Does that help?